# Eclipse editor not supporting java

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I've installed eclipse on my new ubuntu 12.04 setup. I did the install through the software center. I went to create a Java project, but it looks like it doesn't have java development kit on it. I'm not sure why. I have never seen this after installing Eclipse. Any ideas why I wouldn't have any language support? It's basically just a bulky text editor at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Eclipse in Ubuntu Software Center generally needs installation of extra packages, had the same problem many times. I strongly recommend downloading and installing from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2).

Answer (score 1):

You can download the java sdk and development tools right in eclipse which should fix your problem, I had the same problem before and that's how I solved it.